# HashMap have the key of integer[] type though its containsKey method returns false?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

While solving a problem on hackerrank, I found that my output differed from the correct answer because of a logical mistake. I have recreated the logical mistake to explain the situation in a better way.

```java
HashMap<Integer[] , Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();

//both a and b have different hashcode
Integer[] a = {1, 1, 0, 0};
Integer[] b = {1, 1, 0, 0}; 

hm.put(a,1);

if (!hm.containsKey(b)) {
    //key does not exists so, create new one  
    hm.put(b, 1);
}
else {
    //key does exists so, put its value = value + 1
    hm.put(b, hm.get(b)+1); 
}
```

Here hm.containsKey(b) return false but if it returns true my output will match to the correct one. How do I make containsKey(b) return true since content of a and b are equal?

Comment: HashMap<Integer[] , Integer> hm = new HashMap<>(); to HashMap<ArrayList<Integer> , Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();

Comment: It uses equals. But equals is useless with arrays.

Comment: documentation of `containsKey(key)`: returns true if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key k such that Objects.equals(key, k)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use an array as the key of a `HashMap`, since arrays don't override `equals` and `hashCode`, so different array instances that contain the exact same elements are not considered identical by the `HashMap`.

Use `List<Integer>` keys instead.

```
Map<List<Integer>, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();

List<Integer> a = List.of(1, 1, 0, 0);
List<Integer> b = List.of(1, 1, 0, 0);

hm.put(a,1);

if (!hm.containsKey(b)) {
    //key does not exists so, create new one  
    hm.put(b, 1);
}
else {
    //key does exists so, put its value = value + 1
    hm.put(b, hm.get(b)+1); 
}
```